# How do they precisely locate the marker at the *"true"* geographic South Pole?

Tags: measurements, geophysics

So referring to [this page](https://www.coolantarctica.com/Antarctica%20fact%20file/antarctica%20environment/south-pole.php) (I'm sure there are others), they say

> *"A metal marker is placed at the geographic South Pole on January the 1st each year and the pole is moved usually by about 10m as that is how far the ice cap has moved carrying the pole with it from the true South Pole point in the previous year."*

That 10 meters on the Earth is about $ \frac{10}{10,000,000} \times \frac{\pi}{2}$ radians of arc which is about one-third arc second.  I imagine they make precise location in the sky of the position of the sun as it circles around it in the sky.  At the precise South Pole, the zenith of the sun should not change at all.

Now, I can understand how some big telescope that is mounted on a frame dozens of meters large might be positioned with precision of an arc second, but what do they use at the Amundsen-Scott station to do this?  Do they place the instrument right on the spot where they think the precise pole location has *"migrated"* to?  (I understand it's the ice that is moving, not the actual geographic pole, unless there is some kinda wobble going on.)

Comment: I imagine they just use a GPS carry a GPS receiver that locates them to < 10 m accuracy relative to the GPS system (all the satellites).

Comment: [Climate Change Has Shifted the Locations of Earth's North and South Poles](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/climate-change-has-shifted-location-north-south-poles/).

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine in the modern age they do not use local observation of the sky for geolocation. Most likely satellite imagery easily spots the new rotationally stationary point on the ice sheet and the scientists use GPS to move the marker to the proper location.